# OOP: Python - repeated values in method call

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I'm new to OOP python and trying to understand how to handle instances, I have a method:

```py
class Object:

    things = []

    def __init__(self, table):

        self.table = table
        self.things.append(table)

        ( ... )

    def thingy(self):
        return self.db.execute(f"select date, p1, p2 from {self.table}")

    def all_things(self):
        self.things.extend(
            map(lambda t: Object(thing=t + '_thing').thingy(), Constants.THINGS))

        return self.things
```

Now how would I call this object, because my thing is driven by a list from `Constants.THINGS`, I.E: `THINGS = ["table1", "table2" ... ]`, but in order to create the object to call the method `all_things()` - I must have a thing set - even tho the method sets the thing on call ...

This feels a little backward, so would appreciate what it is I am misunderstanding as I think I need to change the constructor/object

```
a = Object(end_date="2020-01-05",
           start_date="2020-01-01",
           thing=WHAT_TO_PUT_HERE).all_things()
```

If I add anything to this `thing` I get a double output

Any help is appreciated

- UPDATE:

The desired output would be that `thing()` will fire, based on a list input provided by `Constants.THINGS`, if we input: `THINGS = ["table1", "table2"]` we would expect `thingy()` to execute twice with:

`select date, p1, p2 from table1`, 
`select date, p1, p2 from table2`

And this would be added to the `things` class variable, and then when `all_things()` finishes we should have the content of the two select statements in a list

However,

`Object.things`

will actually have `[WHAT_TO_PUT_HERE, table_1, table2]`

Comment: `things = []` is a class variable, i.e. static

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the effect of this on my code, and a possible alternative approach? Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Can you give a reproducable example of the output you're expecting?

Comment: In your example `things` is a class variable. It belongs to the class so it can be called without creating an instance `Object.things`. It also retains it's value across all instances so when you create an instance `my_table = Object(table_1)` and another `my_other_table = Object(table_2)` then `Object.things` will contain `[table_1, table_2]`.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense to me, but what would cause `Object.things` to contain `[table_1, table_1, table_2]` as this seems like  strange behavior

Comment: I have updated the original Q, @Axe319,

Comment: Because it's a class variable. It doesn't get reset with every instance like `self.table` would. It is initialized when your class is first interpreted.

Comment: Okay, thank you. -  - If im correct in thinking, I could just have a list of `things` in the constructor and then use `self.things` instead?

Comment: I think I see what you're saying now. `map(self.thingy, Constants.THINGS)` should work on what you're trying to achieve. If you want to call a method from inside the class, simply use `self.method()` since `self` refers to that instance.

Comment: I want to call it outside of the class though, but in order to do so I need to pass a `thing` into the constructor, but the method inside the class is what creates the `thing` so it leads to repetition in the list `things`. As this will contain the inner cass method things and the thing i pass in the constructor to call the method in the first place

Comment: This is a classic http://xyproblem.info. You should describe the problem first, and then go for your attempted solution, so that we can drive you to the right way. If you only describe your attempted solution we can't infer the problem.

Comment: Can I suggest you use clearer variable names than thing, thingy and all_things. You are working with queries and tables, it might be easier to understand if you just name your methods etc after what you actually want them to do.

Comment: In addition, your `__init__` only take one arg, `table` but later you try call it with three, `end_date`, `start_date`, `thing`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So according to your update, this is what I think you're attempting to do.

```
class Object:
    def __init__(self):
        # do some initialization
        pass

    def thingy(self, table):
        return self.db.execute(f"select date, p1, p2 from {table}")

    # call the method "thingy" on all Constants.THINGS
    def all_things(self):
        map(self.thingy, Constants.THINGS)
```

Then from outside the class you would call it like this.

```
my_instance = Object()
my_instance.all_things()
```

I'm assuming the class will also have some setup and teardown of your db connection. As well as some other things but this is simply a minimalistic attempt at giving an example of how it should work.

Comment: Thanks Axe319 - It was simply my understanding of class variables that let me down, which you originally made me aware of. So yes, this is marked as the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so rather than having a class variable which @Axe319 informed me doesn't get reset with every instance as `self.table` would. I altered the constructor to just have:

```
class Object:
    def __init__(self, table):
        self.table = table
        self.things = list()
```

Then when I call the particular method outside the class:

`all_things()` I can just pass `None` into the table as the method builds that for me. i.e:

```
a = Object(thing=None).all_things()
```

This might be an anti-pattern - again I'm new to OOP, but it's creating something that looks correct.

P.S yes I agree, things, thingy, and the thing was a bad choice for variables for this question...

Thanks